# paint.drawArc() does not paint

Tags: java, android, graphics

I am trying to paint a ball that will be divided in 4 colours: green, red, yellow and blue.

Some balls use just one colour, so I paint them like this:

```
 paint.setColor(color);
 canvas.drawCircle(x, y, ballRadius, paint);
```

And they show up on the screen, no problems here.

But when I try to color the other ones, with the same paint and canvas object with this code i get no result on the screen:

```
 RectF rect = new RectF(x - ballRadius, y + ballRadius, x + ballRadius, y - ballRadius);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas.drawArc(rect, 0, 90, true, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawArc(rect, 90, 180, true, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    canvas.drawArc(rect, 180, 270, true, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawArc(rect, 270, 360, true, paint);
```

Comment: I removed Android-Studio, but just to check, you're not talking about in not drawing in the IDE, you mean when running on a device/emulator?

Comment: Yes, sry for that. I am using the IDE, but the I am looking at the result on my device (I am using  my own phone/hardware to run it, not an emulator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RectF rect = new RectF(x - ballRadius, y + ballRadius, x + ballRadius, y - ballRadius);
```

Is incorrect, because the arguments for `RectF` must be in the correct order, [`left, top, right, bottom`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RectF.html#RectF(float,%20float,%20float,%20float)):

> Create a new rectangle with the specified coordinates. Note: no range checking is performed, so the caller must ensure that `left <= right` and `top <= bottom`.

The correct definition of the rectangle (assuming `ballRadius > 0`!) would be:

```
RectF rect = new RectF(x - ballRadius, y - ballRadius, x + ballRadius, y + ballRadius);
```